# How to instantiate different child classes conditionally?

Tags: c++, class, inheritance

For example, in the main function, I want to get the user's input. Depending on the input, I will create either a `Rectangle` or a `Circle`, which are child classes of `Object`. If there's no input (or unknown), then I will just create a generic object.

```
class Object
{ 
       public:
           Object();
           void Draw();
       private:
           ....  
};
class Rectangle:public Object
{ 
       public:
           Rectangle();
           .... //it might have some additional functions
       private:
           ....  
};

class Circle:public Object
{ 
       public:
           Circle();
           .... //it might have some additional functions
       private:
           ....  
};
```

main function:

```
string objType;
getline(cin, objType);

if (!objType.compare("Rectangle"))
     Rectangle obj;
else if (!objType.compare("Circle"))
     Circle obj;
else 
     Object obj;

obj.Draw();
```

Of course, the code above won't work because I can't instantiate an object inside an If statement. So i tried something like this.

```
Object obj;
if (!objType.compare("Rectangle"))
    obj = Rectangle();
else if (!objType.compare("Circle"))
    obj = Circle();


obj.Draw();
```

This code would compile, but it won't do what I want. For some reason, the object was not initiated the way the child class should (for example, I set the some Object's member variables, specifically, a vector,  differently in the child classes). However, when I put a break point at the Child class constructor, it did run through there.

So how should I put instantiate Objects as its child classes in some if-statements??

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You *can* create automatic objects in `if` statements, but they will be destroyed at the end of the scope they are created in so they don't work for this problem.

The reason you can't do the `obj = Rectangle()` one is because of [slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-the-slicing-problem-in-c).

You have to have a pointer to an `Object`. Pointers to base objects can also point to instances of child objects. Then you can dynamically create the object inside the `if` with `new` (objects created with `new` disregard scope and are only destroyed when you call `delete` on a pointer to them), then `delete` it when you're done:

```
Object* obj = NULL; // obj doesn't point to anything yet
string objType;
getline(cin, objType);

if (objType == "Rectangle")
    obj = new Rectangle; // make obj point to a dynamic Rectangle
else if (objType == "Circle")
    obj = new Circle; // make obj point to a dynamic Circle
else
    obj = new Object;  // make obj point to a dynamic Object

obj->Draw(); // draw whatever shape obj really points to

delete obj; // deallocate dynamic object
```

Alternatively, you can use smart pointers and then you don't have to worry about manually deallocating the object:

```
std::unique_ptr<Object> obj(NULL); // obj doesn't point to anything yet
string objType;
getline(cin, objType);

if (objType == "Rectangle")
    obj.reset(new Rectangle); // make obj point to a dynamic Rectangle
else if (objType == "Circle")
    obj.reset(new Circle); // make obj point to a dynamic Circle
else
    obj.reset(new Object);  // make obj point to a dynamic Object

obj->Draw(); // draw whatever shape obj really points to

// the unique_ptr takes care of delete'ing the object for us
// when it goes out of scope
```

Comment: It works!
In addition to the solution to my problem, thanks for giving good explanation to how classes and pointer works in C+++!